# Can we have the flag overlay back for flag-to-closes?

Tags: feature-request, flags

The Great Flag Overhaul seems to have removed the flag overlay from posts that have been flagged to close.

Can we get this back? It used to be useful (especially when trawling the close queue), and I see no reason for removing it.